# In C++, is it okay to implement an iterator interface in which advancing invalidates the "current" element?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, api-design, istream-iterator

I'm designing a C++ interface which allows the user to iterate on objects decoded from a file. This decoding process is somewhat slow.

I'm considering an iterator interface for this, but I want to avoid any unnecessary copy, so I'm thinking about (user's side):

```
for (const auto& object : file) {
    // you can access the members of `object` here
    std::cout << object.whatever() << std::endl;

    // you can copy `object` here
    myObjectCopy = object;

    // you CANNOT do this because `object` changes
    // as soon as the iterator advances
    myObjectPtr = &object;
}
```

`object` in the previous usage example is a reference to an object internal to the iterator instance.

Is this wrong? What other idiomatic interfaces would you suggest here?

I thought about a stream interface (think `std::istream`), but AFAIK, the methods to read data also return copies (they *extract* characters).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like what you're talking about is [an input iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator).

Be sure to inherit your custom iterator class from `std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, decoded_object_type>`. A classical implementation is for `operator*` to cache the decoded object, and return the cached object if it's invoked a second time before `operator++` gets invoked; and `operator++` invoking `operator*` to make sure that the object gets decoded, if it's not already.

Comment: Input iterators are permitted to say "you can only call `*` once, and you must call it before `++`", and actually have `*` do the advancing while `++` is a noop.  Providing more is great, just not required.

Comment: But if `*` does not get invoked, `++` still needs to advance the iterator. So with this approach it becomes necessary for `++` to check if `*` has not been invoked, and invoke it itself.

Comment: No, I claim that is not required.  `++` is permitted to advance, but it may be a noop.  Its precondition satisfies its postcondition.  It may be surprising, but for most uses we won't care.  There is a *note* [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) that implies calling `(void)*i, *i` should be equivalent to `*i`, but notes are not normative; I'd want to double-check in the standard.  Possibly I'm being overly aggressive here, but I've seen many implementations that do exactly that (have `*` read and advance, `++` do nothing), so I'm leery of either interpretation now.

Comment: @Yakk: any reference to support this?

Comment: Anyway, I'm accepting this. I didn't know `InputIterator` had those exact constraints which I need. That's great.

Comment: @Yakk: In C++11 the equivalence of `(void)*a, *a` and `*a` is given in the "Input iterator requirements" table in the "Assertion/note pre-/post-condition" column. (Where -as I get it- notes usually are prefixed "Remark" in this column.)

Comment: @eepp At this point I suspect I'm wrong, and that the input iterators I've seen written like this are in violation.  I have still not standard delved to confirm this.

Comment: What about @Pixelchemist's comment?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's OK.  An iostream is basically the same: if you iterate over the values you get from it, you can copy them, but you cannot hold a pointer to them after the stream or iterator on the stream is advanced.